# Best way to create "virtual" modules in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, architecture, python-module

## Problem description

I have a package with OS-dependent modules. These modules have the same API, each.

In client code I can do something like:

```py
import platform

if platform.system() == "Windows":
  from my_package import os_win32 as my_package_platform
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
  from my_package import os_linux as my_package_platform

# use my_package_platform in client code
```

However I would like to do something like

```py
from my_package import my_package_platform
```

and have it automatically import the right module.

### Possible Solution 1: Real module importing everything from the specific module

Actually have a module `my_package_platform.py`:

```py
import platform
import importlib as imp
import importlib.util as impu
import sys

exports = ["symbol1", "symbol2"]

def update_globals(mod, var_list):
    for var in var_list:
        globals()[var] = mod.__dict__.get(var)


if platform.system() == "Windows":
    mod = imp.import_module(".os_win32", __package__)
elif platform.system() == "Linux":
    mod = imp.import_module(".os_linux", __package__)
else:
    raise NotImplementedError("not implemented for platform %s".format(platform.system()))

update_globals(mod, exports)
```

This seems to work, however seems a bit hacky. Also the `exports` variable has to be maintained.

### Possible solution 2: Using `sys.meta_path` manipulation to create a "virtual module"

Add the following in the `__init__.py` of the package:

```py
import platform
import importlib.abc
import importlib.util as impu
import sys


class _VirtualModuleFinder(importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder):

    def find_spec(self, fullname: str, path, target=None):
        if fullname == __package__ + ".my_package_platform":
            if platform.system() == "win32":
                return impu.find_spec(__package__ + ".os_win32")
            elif platform.system() == "Linux":
                return impu.find_spec(__package__ + ".os_linux")
            else:
                return None


sys.meta_path.append(_VirtualModuleFinder())
```

This works quite elegantly, however it seems a bit overkill. On the other hand, the additional `Finder` is only called when a module is not found by other means.

One caveat is, that the module spec will contain the original module name. (Which might be a bug or a feature - I do not fully understand the implications currently).

### Questions

- Which drawbacks do you see for each method?
- Are there better methods or a "best practice"?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that is less hacked and seems to work better for corner cases:

```py
import platform
import importlib as imp
import importlib.util as impu
import sys

mpp_name = impu.resolve_name(".my_package_platform", __package__)

if mpp_name not in sys.modules:
    if platform.system() == "win32":
        my_package_platform = imp.import_module(".os_win32", __package__)
    elif platform.system() == "Linux":
        my_package_platform = imp.import_module(".os_linux", __package__)
    else:
        raise ValueError("my_package_platform undefined for this platform")

    sys.modules[mpp_name] = my_package_platform
```

Works even with `Mock.patch`. Only IDE integration with PyCharm is lacking - not sure why - I guess they have their own module search algorithm.